# Reconstructing graph to find count of optimized graphs less than initial shortest path

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, shortest-path

I have a graph G = {V,E} with weighted edges (all positive integers) and I have the shortest path of this graph from source vertex A and destination vertex B (lets say this shortest path is equal to 100) found by using Dijkstra's Algorithm.

I want to figure out all the ways that I could reconstruct this graph with the same amount of edges and nodes but modifying the connections between nodes to be the absolute shortest until I reach 100 again (the old shortest path without the reconstruction)

For example, I could reconstruct the graph with A connected to Z with a weight of 1 and my shortest path would therefor be 1 and that would be 1 way of reconstructing the graph. Another way would be A to B to Z with a weight of 1 on each edge to give the total path a distance of 2. However, I also want to count the path that we could reconstruct with A to Z having a weight of 2...99 initially and this would still satisfy the condition of this path being shorter than the first path (100)

I'm trying to figure out a way to find all the possible paths that could be "reconstructed" that have a lower distance than the initial shortest path from the initial graph.

The only constraints are that I must still use all the Vertices and Edges that were in the first graph, but I can change the weight and the edges to be any combination that makes the shortest path shorter than before.

EDIT: The goal is not to find the shortest path, but the maximum amount of graphs that could be reconstructed with a path from A to Z that are less than the initial graph's shortest path from A to Z. See comments below for further clarification.

Comment: 1) When you say 'reconstructed' paths that have a lower distance than the initial shortest path, do you mean shortest weighted path found using Dijkstra? Or do you mean the shortest path irrespective of weight?(example: using Dijkstra on the same graph but all edges have weight one).

Comment: @KellyS.French I mean shortest weighted path. Sorry for the ambiguity.

Comment: 2) When you say that you say you can change the weight and edges, I assume you can change all the weights to 1 but can you introduce new edges because then what would keep you from doing the obviously unrealistic (because I'm missing something in your restrictions) approach of adding a direct edge from A to Z with a weight of one and end up with a shortest path algorithm of O(1)?

Comment: @KellyS.French, you can do exactly what you just described and I would count that as 1 way the graph could be reconstructed. I want to find the maximum number of ways the graph could be reconstructed with any edge being any weight and connected to any vertex, so long as all the vertices are connected and the graph is less than the initial shortest path (in this example 100)

Comment: @KellyS.French, the goal is not to find the shortest path, but the maximum amount of graphs that could be reconstructed that are less than the initial graphs shortest path.

Comment: 3) So you are wanting to produce a path that is A)always shorter in absolute distance compared to Dijkstra, or B) always shorter in weighted distance compared to Dijkstra, or C) either or both of A and B?

Comment: @KellyS.French always shorter in weighted distance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds like an exponential problem because you can arbitrarily add any number of edges between your source and target nodes, and that is for the simplest case where all edges have weight (1).

For purposes of discussion, let's simplify the problem into two sets of graphs, those with all edges having a weight of 1 and another set where all edges have a weight "w" of 2 for a target weighted path "t" of 100.

To show the worst case let's make sure there are plenty of nodes, so for any given set we will assume that there are plenty of nodes "n" to choose from such that

> n >  t / w

so the number of nodes used in the first set has a graph with n > 100+1 and for the second set of nodes the graph must have n > 50+1, and so on.

For a graph with 100+1 nodes using an edge weight of 1, you start with node A and then can choose any remaining node for the next edge. From there you repeat choosing the next node 98 more times after which you connect directly from the current node directly to node Z for the 100th edge.  Since we don't allow loops or weights other than 1 for this scenario, we are done.   This assumes that we have a limited number of nodes to choose from. There are 100 factorial (100!) answers that satisfy your criteria just for the set of graphs with edge weight 1. It becomes a combinatorial problem, especially if you have more nodes than the target path length (n = 200), so it becomes even larger because you can choose from multiple sets of 100 nodes to result in the final path.

For a graph with edge weight 2 you do the same thing but need fewer nodes (50+1) but end up with a similar result of 50!.  Now do that for all edge weights up to 100 (a single edge connecting A and Z) and you have the set of all paths with uniform edge weights that add up to your target length.

So for just the set of graphs with uniform edge weights that are evenly divisible into 100 you would end up with a maximum number of graphs being

> 100! + 50! + 25! + 20! + 10! + 5! + 4! + 2! + 1

From there you still have all the paths with non-uniform weights.  But you can still start by breaking down the non-uniform weight group into subgroups.

When the edge weight isn't evenly divisible into 100 you can still arrive at a value, for example an edge weight of 3 would be (33! + 1), meaning 33 edges of weight 3 and one edge of weight 1, and an edge weight of 6 gives (16! + 4) meaning 16 edges of weight 6 and one edge of weight 4.  We can call these the dual-weight graphs.

Combinatorics sounds like your best bet at that point.

For example, you could start by saying there are n-1 ways to connect A and Z with a single node of weight 100.  I'm not familiar with how to make it show up properly here on Stackoverflow but you are saying choose 1 from a set of n-1.

Then you find all the graphs that have a single path of weight 99 from A to some arbitrary node P and then another edge of weight 1 from P to the target node Z.  So the first edge can be chosen from the # nodes - 2 (exclude both the source and the target nodes) and then the second edge is a given since it must be connected to Z.  This gives us

> (n-2)! + 1

which comes down to "choose 1 from a set of n-2 and then add 1".  Once you get past that it gets really ugly because there starts to be more than one way to choose the remaining edges.

The next case is choose a single node of weight 98 and then find the set of graphs that have a total weight of 2.

It might be simpler to start with a graph with 2 nodes and go up from there to develop a generalized approach.

Basically you have to choose from the number of edges remaining and the edge weight at the same time to give you the set of all graphs that can be connected giving a path length of a given value.

Comment: Thanks Kelly. I know this was an exceptional problem. I am doing it for fun haha. I appreciate the well thought out answer. I may try to implement this later.